# Using Selenium as gateway for other site with asp.net

Tags: asp.net, selenium, proxy

In my asp.net project I am try to send data to selenium web-browser from webform while selenium browser is working. For example, there is a textbox and button in my webform.When I write text and click button. It starts selenium browser, login page go to messages and send text which i wrote. But when i wanna send another message text in same page, because of postback it starts proggress from begining. In this case i need browser standby , wait me enter another text from my webform and submits it again.Here is my code behind;

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    IWebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
    driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("https://www.somesite.com/");
    IWebElement query = driver.FindElement(By.Name("username"));
    query.SendKeys("blablabla");
    driver.FindElement(By.Name("password")).SendKeys("blablabla");
    driver.FindElement(By.Id("btnLogin")).Submit();
    new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(7));
    driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("https://www.somesite.com/sendmessage/john");
    new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30)).Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementExists((By.LinkText("Message"))));

    driver.FindElement(By.LinkText("Message")).Click();
    driver.FindElement(By.LinkText("MessageText")).SendKeys(txtMessage.Text);


    Actions action = new Actions(driver);
    action.SendKeys(Keys.Enter);
    action.Perform();
}
```

Comment: here , where you are inserting text 2 times?

Comment: @rahulbhatt pardon me?